# Value of char pointer changes after assigning to another char pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I am treating "arr" as an array of "pointers to char". Why does the address change after assigning the char pointers from "arr" to "first" and "second" in the code below?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
        char * arr = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char *) * 2);
        char * first;
        char * second;

        ((char **)&arr)[0] = "ABCD";
        ((char **)&arr)[1] = "EFGH";

        printf("BEFORE : ((char **)&arr)[0] = %s, Address: %p \n",((char **)&arr)[0], ((char **)&arr)[0] );
        printf("BEFORE : ((char **)&arr)[1] = %s, Address: %p \n",((char **)&arr)[1], ((char **)&arr)[1] );

        first = ((char **)&arr)[0];
        second = ((char **)&arr)[1];

        printf("AFTER : ((char **)&arr)[0] = %s, Address: %p \n",((char **)&arr)[0], ((char **)&arr)[0] );
        printf("AFTER : ((char **)&arr)[1] = %s, Address: %p \n",((char **)&arr)[1], ((char **)&arr)[1] );

        printf("first = %s\n",first);
        printf("second = %s\n",second);

return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
BEFORE : ((char **)&arr)[0] = ABCD, Address: 0x400708 
BEFORE : ((char **)&arr)[1] = EFGH, Address: 0x40070d 
AFTER : ((char **)&arr)[0] = ABCD, Address: 0x400708 
AFTER : ((char **)&arr)[1] = ABCD, Address: 0x400708 
first = ABCD
second = ABCD
```

**Edit:**

```
I am using gcc version 4.8.2
```

Comment: which compiler are you using? I don't see a problem by clang-503.0.40

Comment: @WayneWang: The code has undefined behaviour, see my answer below.

Comment: @NPE Yes, assign string literal to 'char *' object and use it afterwards can cause undefined behaviour. Thanks mention that.

Answer (score 4):

Your code has [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in the following expressions:

```
    ((char **)&arr)[1]
```

Did you mean to write

```
    ((char **)arr)[1]
```

?

By the way, if you declared `arr` to be of the correct type in the first place, you wouldn't need the tedious and error-prone casts:

```
int main() {
        char ** arr = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 2);
        char * first;
        char * second;

        arr[0] = "ABCD";
        arr[1] = "EFGH";

        printf("BEFORE : arr[0] = %s, Address: %p \n", arr[0], arr[0]);
        printf("BEFORE : arr[1] = %s, Address: %p \n", arr[1], arr[1]);

        first = arr[0];
        second = arr[1];

        printf("AFTER : arr[0] = %s, Address: %p \n", arr[0], arr[0]);
        printf("AFTER : arr[1] = %s, Address: %p \n", arr[1], arr[1]);

        printf("first = %s\n", first);
        printf("second = %s\n", second);

        free(arr);

        return 0;
}
```